# File download issue using PHP. PDFs works, but Images (jpg) corrupted

Tags: php, image, pdf, download

I've tried a few Stackoverflow solutions for this, but struggling for a workable solution.

I have an existing script that works and downloads PDFs correctly, and I now also need to be able to download images (JPGs mainly).

However when the image file downloads, it is corrupted and doesn't open. What am I missing.

Here what I have:

```
    $PDF['FilePath'] = '/2022/04/testfile.jpg';
    $Path = "/var/directory/folder";
    $Document = $Path . $PDF['FilePath'];
    $PathParts = pathinfo($PDF['FilePath']);
    $ImageMime = getimagesize($Document);
    
    if (file_exists($Document) && $PathParts['extension'] == 'pdf')
    {
        set_time_limit(0);
        header('Connection: Keep-Alive');
        header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
        header('Content-Type: application/pdf');
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=". basename($Item['FilePath']));
        header('Expires: 0');
        header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
        header('Pragma: public');
        header('Content-Length: '. filesize($Document));
        readfile($Document);
        exit;
    } else {
        header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
        header("Content-Type:".$ImageMime['mime']);
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=". basename($PDF['FilePath']));
        header('Expires: 0');
        header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
        header('Pragma: public');
        header('Content-Length:'. filesize($Document));
        readfile($Document);
        exit;
        
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure that it's the problem with download image? I can't reproduce as it seems to download correctly. I can only see that you called to `$Item['FilePath']` in PDF part but this variable is not exists.

Comment: Do some basic debugging ... start by verifying that your variables actually contain what you think they should. Also, open the downloaded image file with a text or hex editor, and see if you can find any error messages in there (and make sure you have proper PHP error reporting enabled, if not already the case.) And finally, write code that makes a bit more sense - currently, your script could go into the else branch, if `file_exists($Document)` was not true to begin with - what sense does that make, when you want to _use_ `$Document` in the else branch ...?